# Comparing two csv files using comm

Tags: bash, csv, mutt, comm

I am working on a script that verifies differences between two csv files (file_1.csv and file_2.csv).

file_1.csv = tasks to be processed

file_2.csv = tasks already processed

- If there is no difference, nothing should be done.
- If there is a difference, file_1.csv should replace file_2.csv, and file_1.csv sent by email. Finally, file_1.csv is deleted.

For that, I wrote the following but it seems it doesn't work.
Apparently the first "comm" command works but it is stuck at this stage.

> if comm -3 file_1.csv file_2.csv;
>
> then
>
> ```
> mv file_1.csv file_2.csv
> mutt -s "subject" -a file_1.csv -- somebody@domain.com < body_email.txt 
> rm file_1.csv
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
> exit
> ```
>
> fi

The output of "if comm -3" is displayed in the prompt but I don't get the prompt back.

Can anyone please advise me what's wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: what do you mean by 'stuck at this stage'? are you getting errors? is your code hanging? is your code not doing what you want (and if so, what is it doing)?  also ... you state `file_1.csv should replace file_2.csv` but your code is replacing `file_2.csv` with the results of the `comm -3` command; I'm also assuming you want one set of lines copied to `file_2.csv` but the `comm -3` is going to generate 2 sets of lines so ... it would also help if we had samples of the 2x files (with differences) and the expected contents of the 'new' `file_2.csv`

Comment: Indeed, I better use "mv file_1.csv file_2.csv". I am saying that the script seems to be stuck because the result of comm command is displayed in the prompt but there is no e-mail being sent and I am not getting the prompt back if I run the script. I have to press ctrl + C to get it back.

Comment: please update the question with those details; as for the `comm -3` output being sent to your console ... that would be the `if comm -3 ...` ... you've not told it what to with the output so the output is dumped to stdout (ie, your console); try `if comm -3 ... >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...` to redirect stdout/stderr to /dev/null

Comment: as for the hang (and need to enter ^C) ... I'm guessing an issue with `mutt` (sorry, I don't use `mutt`) or the `rm` possibly asking for confirmation??; try `set -x; if ...fi; `set +x` to see which command is hanging

Comment: If you move file_1 to file_2, there will be no file_1 to mail, better you copy and then remove

Comment: I edited the question as requested. I replaced "mv" command by "cp", and I removed "rm" command which actually wasn't necessary and it seems to be working fine now. And mutt command was good as it works if I run it standalone. Thank you all for your great support.

Comment: Thank you all. Indeed, mv command was generating troubles, I replaced it by cp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to sort the files before comparing, try:

`comm -23 <(sort -u file_1) <(sort -u file_2)`

this would give you all tasks that have not been processed

For example, try the below code snippet:

```
diff=`comm -23 <(sort -u file_1) <(sort -u file_2)`
if [ $diff > 0 ]
then
    cp file_1 file_2
    mutt -s "subject" -a file_1.csv -- somebody@domain.com < body_email.txt
    rm file_1.csv
fi
```